# Check constraint for start/end date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a 'start_date' attribute and an 'end_date' attribute. I want to create a check constraint in Oracle that prevents the end_date from preceding the start_date and the start_date from exceeding the end_date. Anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `CHECK` **[constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm)**:

```
ALTER TABLE tableX
  ADD CONSTRAINT end_date_later_than_start_date_CK   -- a sensible name 
                                                     -- for the constraint
    CHECK (start_date <= end_date) 
    <optional constraint state>
;
```

The optional constraint states are described in the link. For example, you can specify `ENABLE NOVALIDATE`, if you want to enable the constraint for future insertions (and updates) but not check existing rows.

Comment: you might want to take `NULL` values into account

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What do you suggest? As it is, if any of the 2 columns is null, a row will pass the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle person but I found this on the web and it may helps. Take the timespan for these two dates. Here is a link for documentation :

[INTERVAL Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/expressions9a.htm#1033525)